# Android Tabhost - Same view in each tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-memory

I have an activity with a tabhost on it.

At runtime my app is connecting to a database and pulling back employee info.  I want to have a tab per employee where the content is displayed in the same way, but with different data.

I have an xml view which I can use for the employee info (just textviews, image etc). When I receive the new data from the database I do the following for each employee:

1. Add a new tab to the tabhost
2. Inflate an 'employee' view.
3. Set the textview text to the values corresponding to the employee.
4. Create a TabSpec from the 'employee' view.
5. Add the the tabspec as a new tab.

I'm currently clearing all tabs and readding every time I get a change in the data and I'm running out of VM memory due to the Bitmaps.   Is this the best way to do this or is there a better one?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid Out Of Memory issues please you can use "load bitmap in sample size" pattern : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Caching bitmaps is also a good practice, check this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html